# Writing to a file - robust commands mess the text file written

Tags: macros, auxiliary-files

I'm writing some lines to a file but I've found that robust commands damages the written file. In this context `\plural` can be a fragile command but in the real application it must be robust. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\immediate\newwrite\txtfile
\immediate\openout\txtfile=\jobname.txt
\DeclareRobustCommand{\plural}[3]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\woman}[1]{#1 \plural{#1}{woman}{women}}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write\txtfile{\woman{1}}
\immediate\write\txtfile{\woman{2}}
\end{document}
```

I want a way in which the text file shows '1 woman' and in the next line '2 women', defining `\plural` as robust.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only a subset of the TeX language is available, if text is written to a file.
The expandable machinery is working, but assignments and other unexpandable stuff is not.

In this case `\plural` can be made expandable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\immediate\newwrite\txtfile
\immediate\openout\txtfile=\jobname.txt

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\plural}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1=1 %
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\woman}[1]{#1 \plural{#1}{woman}{women}}

\begin{document}
\immediate\write\txtfile{\woman{1}}
\immediate\write\txtfile{\woman{2}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
1 woman
2 women
```

**Remarks:**

- Because `\plural` is full expandable, it is already robust and `\DeclareRobustCommand` is not needed.
- The comparison is done via the expandable `\ifnum`, `\ifthenelse` is not expandable.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using `\write` when the argument contains macros that should be “protected” or are defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`. A `\protected@immediatewrite` macro can be defined using the definition of `\protected@write` as a model:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\immediate\newwrite\txtfile
\immediate\openout\txtfile=\jobname.txt

\makeatletter
\long\def\protected@immediatewrite#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \let\thepage\relax
  #2%
  \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}%
  \reserved@a
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}

\newcommand\lazowrite[1]{\protected@immediatewrite\txtfile{}{#1}}
\makeatother

\DeclareRobustCommand{\plural}[3]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\woman}[1]{#1 \plural{#1}{woman}{women}}
\begin{document}
\lazowrite{\woman{1}}
\lazowrite{\woman{2}}
\end{document}
```

Here `\lazowrite` is just syntactic sugar around `\protected@immediatewrite`.

In case you plan to use `\nofiles`, you should add

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\nofiles{%
  \long\def\protected@immediatewrite#1#2#3{%
    \immediate\write\m@ne{}\if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

before `\documentclass`.

---

A LaTeX3 implementation; with `\int_case:nnF` the command can be more flexible, allowing for many cases in an expandable way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% allocate a write stream
\iow_new:N \g_lazo_output_iow
\iow_open:Nn \g_lazo_output_iow { \c_job_name_tl .txt }

% User interface
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\plural}{mmm}
 {
  \lazo_plural:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
% Inner function
\cs_new:Npn \lazo_plural:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   { { 1 }{ #2 } }
   { #3 }
 }
% User interface
\NewDocumentCommand{\lazowrite}{m}
 {
  \lazo_write:n { #1 }
 }
% Inner function
\cs_new_protected:Npn \lazo_write:n #1
 {
  \iow_now:Nx \g_lazo_output_iow { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\woman}[1]{#1 \plural{#1}{woman}{women}}

\begin{document}

\lazowrite{\woman{1}}
\lazowrite{\woman{2}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But \jobname.txt reads:  \protect \plural {1}{woman}{women}   \protect \plural {2}{woman}{women}

Comment: @EmilioLazo That's exactly what's expected, isn't it?

Comment: Nope, sorry... '\protect \plural {1}{woman}{women} [...]' isn't what I want in txt file. I want in txt file the output of '\woman{x}' like issuing it in the document; e.g. '\woman{1}' would put '1 woman' in txt file, like Heiko's solution, but I'm interested also in yours!

Comment: @EmilioLazo If you want `1 woman` in the text file, you need fully expandable functions. I'll add something later.

Comment: Thanks! An upgrade of the l3kernel was needed on my system. I was using 2013-07-12 and your code gave an error on \int_case:nnF but with latest LaTeX3 implementation (2013-07-28) worked like expected. Also writelatex.com needs this update!

Comment: As of September 2015, `\c_job_name_tl` should become `\c_sys_jobname_str` (no other change is necessary).