# Write fully expanded macros to auxiliary files

Tags: expansion, xparse, write, robust-commands, protected-macro

Considering the following code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\NewDocumentCommand{\edeftest}{m}{\edef\test{#1}#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\edeftestii}{m}{\edef\testii{#1}#1}

\def\yy#1{inserted by yy -#1- inserted by yy}
\NewDocumentCommand{\zz}{m}{inserted by zz -#1- inserted by zz}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\robusttest}{robust}

\newwrite\txt
\immediate\openout\txt=\jobname.txt

\begin{document}
\edeftest{test - \yy{argument of yy}}\par
\edeftestii{test - \zz{argument of zz}}\par
\immediate\write\txt{\test}
\immediate\write\txt{\testii}
\show\test
\show\testii

\edeftest{test - \yy{argument of yy} - diacritics: á\'a - \robusttest}\par
\edeftestii{test - \zz{argument of zz} - diacritics: á\'a - \robusttest}\par
\immediate\write\txt{\test}
\immediate\write\txt{\testii}
\show\test
\show\testii

\immediate\closeout\txt
\end{document}
```

The first run of `\edeftest` writes the (my) expected behavior: `\test` macro is defined as `test - inserted by yy -argument of yy- inserted by yy`, as shown when `\show\test` is being executed. The first run of `\edeftestii` doesn't expands the `\zz` macro; I don't want that.

The second run of `\edeftest` and `\edeftestii` are worse. Both diacritics (`á` and `\'a`) were written to the `\test` and `\testii` macros (and to the txt file) with the `TeX` expanded semantic, i.e. `\unhbox \voidb@x (...) \accent (...)` unless we uncomment the T1 font encoding package at preamble, in which case, both accented "a" characters are in `iso-8859-1` encoding not in `UTF8`, I guess because `pdfLaTeX` isn't an Unicode engine. Compiling with `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX` these characters are treated as `UTF8` without issues: both macros and the `.txt` file contains `áá`. This is good for me but I would like a way to having this behavior compiling using `pdfLaTeX`.

Finally, in the second test set, the robust macro inserts the expected but undesired `\protect` primitive to the `.txt` file.

What I want? The ultimate goal is having a `txt` file whose contents is as closer as possible to the fully expanded macros `\test` and `\testii` or whatever argument the user inserts to the `\edeftest` macro. Closer as possible means closest to the text of the compiled document, so for example, some typographic change (`\bfseries`, `\textbf`, `\fontsize`) would be fine if were removed from the `txt` file. It is possible? I know when writing auxiliary files we have some limitations, that's why I emphasize the word "CLOSER".

How can `\edeftest` be defined to achieve that?

I know the trick `\begingroup\edef{\endgroup` but I could not use this here. Also some years ago I did ask a related question [1], it served for me on that scenario but here don't.

[1] [Writing to a file - robust commands mess the text file written](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127031/writing-to-a-file-robust-commands-mess-the-text-file-written)

Comment: How about `\makeatletter
\protected@write{\txt}{}{\testii}
\makeatother`? or `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\zz}{...}`... `\zz` isn't expandable as it is defined by you

Comment: currently (this might change) characters are written out in their internal form (so `á` and `\'a` are written out as `\'a` if you use supported commands so not `\edef` and `\write` but `\protected@edef` and `\protected@write`.  Your description isn't accurate: with  `[utf8]` inputenc  the characters won't be converted to latin1.  But your requests are contradictory, you can fully expand everything but (in pdftex) á  is two adjacent characters and macros combining those, converting  to `\'{a}` and if typesetting  to the glyph or `\accent` construct. To get `á` you want to _suppress_  expansion.

Comment: see egreg's answer to the question that you link to, as he says there you should not be using `\write`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and @ChristianHupfer, the `\protected@write` solution does not work for `\zz`. Both egreg's solutions does the same as here described: `\zz` is written unexpanded and `\protect` string is also written to the text file. Is that avoidable? (Assuming that `\zz` and `\robusttest` should remain as it are defined)

Comment: that is what the protected  commands do, prevent expansion. You could use xparse's ExpandableDocumentCommand declarations to define macros that disappear, but as I said above your intentions are not clear as the stated aims are in direct contradiction. You either need to suppress expansion if you want á written as á or if you want "full expansion" then you will get whatever á expands to.  Either way, `\edef` and `\write` are not supported commands to apply to arbitrary sequences of latex commands.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I agree in what you said about the expansion of "á". I would like to have no macros in text file, i.e. writing `\test` and `\testii` to the auxiliary file would produce a text closer to how this text is seen on the compiled pdf when issuing these macros on the document. That's all.